# Meu try não está lendo meu except

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
        try:
            idade = int(input(f'Digite a idade da pessoa {c+1}: '))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            if idade < 18:
                listaidademenorde18.append(idade)
            elif idade >= 18:
                listaidademaiorde18.append(idade)
            break
```

Meu código dá erro quando eu digito um valor que não é um `int` na variável `int`, mesmo eu tendo coloca o `except ValueError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que deu para entender criou um laço para ficar repetindo o pedido do dado até que ele seja válido. Deve ter um outro laço mais externo que controla quantos dados foram entrados, vou ignorar essa parte porque ela nem está completa.

O problema é o `else`. Primeiro, deve achar que esse bloco executa se não cair no `except`, mas na verdade ele cai em todas as vezes, dando exceção ou não, e não parece ser o que deseja.

Na verdade parece que esses `if`s não fazem parte da validação, é um código que deve executar sempre que o dado for válido e esse laço é sobre ser inválido, então esse `if` deve estar fora do laço, ele deve executar todas as vezes logo depois que saiu do laço.

A única decisão a fazer ali é se deve continuar ou não no laço. O `except` está certo, se der erro deve pedir de novo, então precisa fazer nada. Se não der erro deve encerrar o laço com um `break`.

Algo que talvez não saiba é que se der erro o fluxo normal não executa, então pode colocar o `break` no fluxo normal, ele só será executado se não der erro, que é exatamente o que deseja, se for digitado algo válido deve sair do laço. A exceção é um controle de fluxo excepcional, se a lógica dele é confusa perde a razão de existir.

Eu poderia manter o `continue`, mas achei mais semântico ter o `pass`, porque ele deve continuar o fluxo normal partindo da li e não pular tudo o que tem depois do código. Mas pode ser interpretação errada minha de acordo com o problema apresentado (não tem tantos detalhes).

```
listaidademenorde18 = []
listaidademaiorde18 = []
while True:
    try:
        idade = int(input('Digite a idade da pessoa: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
if idade < 18:
    listaidademenorde18.append(idade)
else:
    listaidademaiorde18.append(idade)
print(listaidademenorde18)
print(listaidademaiorde18)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZRDR2k). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mllhbfzm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ExceptElse.py).

Aproveito para conceituar algo que a pergunta entende errado.

Você não está digitando um `int` ou outro tip ode dado quando o `input()` pede um dado. Está digitando sempre um texto, só isso. Existem textos que podem ser transformados em um dado numérico inteiro porque todos os caracteres são dígitos numéricos. Então sendo possível fazer a conversão você terá um dado que será do tipo `Number` e que será inteiro porque foi usado uma função de conversão que gera um valor inteiro sempre, se possível, se não for possível gera uma exceção, então o `input()` não tem nada a ver com isso. E não existe variável `int`.